# hwo to fetch upper data and then delete in one action in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I just want to fetch the upper data only and then delete it in one action.
I tried this code:

```
`def Data(request):
     data =  Plan.objects.get(id = 1)
     data.delete()
     context = {'data':data}    
     return render(request,'data.html',context)`
```

But didn't work.

[see Database column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEepr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand, what is not works. Try to write a little bit more about your problem. Probably this can help:

```
def Data(request):
     data =  Plan.objects.get(id = 1)
     Plan.objects.filter(id = 1).delete()
     return render(request,'data.html',{'data':data})`
```